# Response header Content-Type: application/xop+xml and lxml.etree.fromstring parsing

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, lxml

I have a Response from a SOAP API which has a Content-Type: application/xop+xml. I am not sure how efficently I can take the Response.text to have `lxml.etree.fromstring` to get the xml to use.

Here is the Response.text

```
 --uuid:051145c9-9210-4e26-a390-d7cdd06b9f94
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><listResponse xmlns="http://www.strongmail.com/services/v2/schema"><objectId xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="UserId"><id>101</id></objectId><objectId xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="UserId"><id>102</id></objectId><objectId xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="UserId"><id>103</id></objectId><objectId xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="UserId"><id>107</id></objectId><objectId xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="UserId"><id>108</id></objectId><objectId xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="UserId"><id>109</id></objectId></listResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
--uuid:051145c9-9210-4e26-a390-d7cdd06b9f94--
```

Taking the .text and having etree.fromstring parse it

```
from lxml import etree
resXML = etree.fromstring(theResponse.text)
```

Gives the following:

```
    resXML = etree.fromstring(theResponse.text)
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3222, in lxml.etree.fromstring
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1877, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1758, in lxml.etree._parseDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1068, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseUnicodeDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 601, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 711, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 640, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
  File "<string>", line 1
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1
```

I believe this is because it was expecting '<' as the first thing as all xml starts with that.

I have looked around in the `lxml.etree` doc https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#parsing-from-strings-and-files and found `.parse` but that is only on files. Looking at methods for Response I can see I can get information on headers, like the content type, though the documentation goes on with json,

Is there some method in Response which can extract just the xml part excluding the headers, or is there one in the lxml.etree?

Comment: To begin with `Response.text` is not valid XML. Can you share your whole code so we can see what is happening?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I am using zeep as a SOAP client, which sends a SOAP request to the SOAP service. It has a setting allowing the response to not be processed by zeep, but be a regular `requests.Response` object. See [zeep settings Docs](https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/settings.html) for an example of how this is set, and is implemented in the code.

Would this code still be required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle it this way:

```
theResponse = [your response above]

from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO

parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree   = etree.parse(StringIO(theResponse), parser)
```

From this point on, lxml can handle it. For a random example, if you are after the links in the response, you can try:

```
for i in tree.iter():
if len(i.values())>0:
       print(i.values()[0])
```

And the output will be:

```
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
http://www.strongmail.com/services/v2/schema
http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I am now digging deeper into the lxml and I see how your answer get's it into the tree.

Comment: @dbjock  Glad it helped!